# Cast a data type with the odbc excel driver

Tags: vb.net, excel, odbc

I'm using the Microsoft Excel Driver to import an Excel document into a adodb.recordset so that I can remove duplicate rows and put it into the SQL Server database.

The first column has values like 192, 13U, JJJ, etc. but for some reason the query casts it as a double value, and any rows with alpha values get converted to Null. From what I can tell this is because the Majority type is numeric instead of text.

I tried casting it, but got an error.

Here's my function:

```
Function Read_Excel(ByVal sFile As String) As ADODB.Recordset
    On Error GoTo fix_err
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sconn As String

    rs.CursorLocation = ADODB.CursorLocationEnum.adUseClient
    rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
    rs.LockType = ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockBatchOptimistic

    sconn = "DRIVER=Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls); ImportMixedTypes=Text; " & "DBQ=" & sFile & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"
    rs.Open("SELECT Code, Description FROM [sheet1$]", sconn)
    tot += rs.RecordCount
    rs.Close()
    rs.Open("SELECT Distinct * FROM [sheet1$]", sconn)
    Read_Excel = rs
    rs = Nothing
    Exit Function
fix_err:
    Debug.Print(Err.Description + " " + _
                Err.Source, vbCritical, "Import")
    Err.Clear()
End Function
```

Is there a way to get the first column as text easily?

EDIT: When I try to `"SELECT cast(RPOCode as varchar(10)), Description FROM [sheet1$]"` I get this error
"[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'cast(Code as varchar)'. Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"
I've tried varchar, varchar(10) and text as the casting types with the same result.

Comment: **WHAT** error did you get?!?! We're not mind-readers - you need to let us know!

Comment: "[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'cast(Code as varchar)'. Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"
I've tried varchar and text as the casting types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
 rs.Open("SELECT CStr([Code]), Description FROM [sheet1$]", sconn)
```

Cast is not available in Jet/ACE SQL.

Comment: That gets rid of the error, but instead of Null I just get an empty string, like it's converting the Null to a string.

Comment: That part about ACE helped me figure it out. I remember seeing that on http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel but hadn't thought to try it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying the ACE connection string instead of the one for Microsoft Excel Driver.

```
sconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & sFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
```

and made sure that the IMEX=1 part was in there. I don't think that the Microsoft Excel Driver was using the Extended Properties correctly.